# Submit de un formulario pulsando un link

Tags: javascript, formularios

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo el siguiente trozo de codigo.

```
 <li>
       <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST" id="cerrarSesion">
           <input type="hidden" name="uAccion" value="Salir">
           <a href="#" id="salir"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
       </form>

</li>
```

Necesito hacer el submit del form, cuando pulso el link. He porbado con jquery

```
$('#salir').click(function(){
    $('#cerrarSesion').submit();

});
```

Tambien poniendo el submit en un onclick en el link, pero no consigo nada... Alguna sugerencia? Un saludo

EDIT:
Ahora ya me funciona, quite el form por completo y lo puse de nuevo y le añadi esto :

```
    $('#salir').click(function(){

           $('#cerrar').submit(); 

    });
```

Gracias por las respuestas ;)

Comment: ¿Cómo has intentado hacer el submit dentro del `onclick`? En principio con eso bastaría...

Comment: onclick="form.submit();"

Comment: Ese código que tienes es suficiente para el submit, si pones `console.log('HOla Mundo')`antes del submit, lo imprime?

Comment: En principio no tendría que darte ningún problema. ¿Te da algún error en la consola?

Comment: VM309 ControladorInicial:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM309 ControladorInicial:147)

Comment: Ese error es normalmente porque tu selector `$('#cerrarSesion')` no encontró ningún elemento, por lo que no puedes aplicarle la función de `submit()` habría que incluir más código JS y HTML para poder detectar de donde pudiera generarse ese error, porque con lo que nos pones en estos momentos todo funciona bien.

Comment: @Lixus hellou, me parecía raro que no funcionara esa forma desde un principio, tengo varios javascript así, y yo me decía "es esto brujería?"

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla y con JavaScript Puro seria:

```
<script>
    function cerrar() {
    document.cerrarSesion.submit();
    }
</script>

<li>
  <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST" id="cerrarSesion">
    <input type="hidden" name="uAccion" value="Salir">
    <a href="#" id="salir" onclick="cerrar();"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Una version aun mas sencilla y portable:

```
 <li>
  <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST" id="cerrarSesion">
    <input type="hidden" name="uAccion" value="Salir">
    <a href="#" id="salir" onclick="this.form.submit()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
  </form>
</li>
```

**¿Como funciona?:**

Usamos la propiedad `submit()` y el `this` para referirnos al formulario actual, seguido del `form`.

Si aun no funciona:

```
<li>
  <form action="ControladorUsuario" method="POST" id="cerrarSesion">
    <input type="hidden" name="uAccion" value="Salir">
    <a href="#" id="salir" onclick="document.getElementById('cerrarSesion').submit();"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Salir</a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar :S

Comment: VM309 ControladorInicial:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM309 ControladorInicial:147)

Comment: @urrutias revisa de nuevo la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he  logrado con Bootstrap 4 de la siguiente manera:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="valor">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

De esta forma se muestra como link, no muestra ningún botón, y se envía adecuadamente el valor de tu variable para procesarlo.